# Whats the best way to get Cart ID from Mageno2 Checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, guest-checkout

I am trying to get the cart_id in my controller but it seems to only be available on the frontend in `knockoutjs`.

Does anyone know how to access this value which is an alpha numeric string used to place and order when calling `GuestPaymentInformationManagement` it passes `$cart_id` as a variable to the `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` function but I cannot find this variable in the backend but it is available on the frontend checkout as `quote.quoteId()` But I need to get this item in the backend if anyone knows how I'd really appreciate it.

```
$cart_id = 'd8sXVE1acGcxJpNnleA3e2gkSq6Zo4ae'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cart_id` you are talking about corresponds to the masked quote id.

In order to get the original quote id from masked quote id you can inject the `Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory` in your construct method and use it like this in a controller (for example):

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = $this->_jsonHelper->jsonDecode($this->getRequest()->getContent());
    $maskedQuoteId = $data['quoteId'];
    $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($maskedQuoteId, 'masked_id');
    $quoteId = $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();
}
```

Comment: I literally just found it in: `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
` then came back to answer my own question - thanks!